# Calling a shell script from a makefile?

Tags: node.js, shell, permissions, makefile, executable

I have a custom shell script to make twitter bootstrap from source and then move the files to my node.js app's /lib file:

```
rm -r bootstrap
make bootstrap
mv -f bootstrap/css/* ../../lib/public/css
mv -f bootstrap/img/* ../../lib/public/img
mv -f bootstrap/js/* ../../lib/public/js
```

Running this from the shell works just fine using ./make_bootstrap.sh

Now I've created a Makefile for my full app (mainly compiling coffeescript and easy test initialization) and want to have a command that executes this custom shell script to build bootstrap. Here is my makefile

```
REPORTER = spec

all: build

build:
    @./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee \
        -c \
        -o lib src

bootstrap:
    @./src/bootstrap \
        ./make_bootstrap.sh

clean:
    rm -rf lib
    mkdir lib

watch:
    @./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee \
        -o lib \
        -cw src

test:
    @./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha \
        --reporter $(REPORTER) \
        test/*.coffee

.PHONY: build bootstrap clean watch test
```

with the relevant command being 'make bootstrap'. However when I run make bootstrap from the command line all I get is this error:

```
make: ./src/bootstrap: Permission denied
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 1
```

Originally I had assumed that it was a permission error but even setting all permissions on files (chmod 777) results in nothing. Files I have given full permissions at this point include the root Makefile, my custom shell script in the bootstrap folder and the makefile within the bootstrap folder itself.

Comment: What is `./src/bootstrap`? Because you are trying to execute it, rather than your script.

Comment: Do you have permission to access the folder as well. You not only need file permission, but also read permission for the containing folder.

Comment: Is ./src/bootstrap the directory containing your bootrstrap source? Why are you trying to execute a directory as a command? Maybe it's supposed to be something like `cd src/bootstrap; ./make_bootstrap`.

Comment: There also seems to be a circularity. The script runs `make bootstrap`, but the makefile runs the script. Unless they're in different directories so they're using different makefiles.

Comment: @Barmar, it looks to me as if the makefile runs `./src/bootstrap` and passes it "./make_bootstrap.sh" as an argument, which sets off a lot of alarm bells but isn't necessarily circular.

Comment: ./src/bootstrap is the directory containing my custom script (make_bootstrap.sh). I'll play around with thoughts from these comments beta that was what I was trying to accomplish yet. @Barmar yes different directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Based on the comments I have refactored to this

```
bootstrap:
    rm -r src/bootstrap/bootstrap
    $(MAKE) -C ./src/bootstrap bootstrap
    mv -f src/bootstrap/bootstrap/css/* lib/public/css
    mv -f src/bootstrap/bootstrap/img/* lib/public/img
    mv -f src/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/* lib/public/js
```

This duplicates the functionality of the shell script I had before (moving files for my custom project) and still uses the standard makefile that Twitter Bootstrap ships with. Much cleaner... I'm going to live the original answer below so people can see the evolution and refactor.

OLD ANSWER

Ok thank you guys in the comments for pointing my in the right direction. This solution works:

```
bootstrap:
    cd ./src/bootstrap; \
        ./make_bootstrap.sh
```

What happens is it executes the change directory (in a sub process so it doesn't affect where I run make from) and then executes the custom script. It seems as if I probably shouldn't be using something like this in a makefile since it feels 'dirty'; perhaps a more clean way to do it would be to invoke the LESS compiler myself and mimic the makefile provided by bootstrap. I'm using this for a tiny personal project though so it does the job.

Comment: There must be a makefile in `./src/bootstrap`. I suggest you move the `mv` commands into that makefile, change the command in this answer to `$(MAKE) -C ./src/bootstrap bootstrap`, and do away with the script altogether.

Comment: You should continue to use the makefile provided with bootstrap, but you could move the commands out of your script and into your main makefile, since they're so simple.

Comment: Thanks guys for the tips on the refactor, see my answer for what I have settled on. No more shell scripts and its a pure makefile! Much prettier than what this repo looked like this afternoon.